# Node.js interpreter Architecture

Tags: node.js, v8

I am new to Node.js and trying to understand more about it. I have installed Node.js on Windows and explored the installed folder to look up the V8 VM but I could n't find it. How are Node.js scripts interpreted through V8, what's the architecture of it?

Comment: The v8 engine is embedded in a javascript interpreter called node (node.exe probably in windows). Just like the v8 engine that's embedded in the javascript interpreter called Google Chrome (chrome.exe probably)

Comment: @slebetman can you give more clarity on architecture?

Comment: Do you want to understand the C code or do you just want to run javascript programs?

Answer (score 0):

The V8 binary is statically linked to the node.exe binary